# How to get heat colors with plot3d in scilab?

Tags: colors, plot, scilab, altitude, mplot3d

Hi this may seem to be a simple question but I am having a hard time understanding how to use the colors in a plot3d.

That is what I have:

```
// x, y and z are matrix 4 by 100

myColors = ones(1,size(z,2));
plot3d(x,y,list(z,myColors),alpha=0,theta=270);
```

I would like to have myColors related to the altitude of z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

If I understand correct x, y and z are something like:

```
x = [ 1:100 ];
y = [ 1:4 ];

z = rand( length(x), length(y) ); //Some function resulting in (100 x 4) matrix
```

Then you can plot it using the following code.

```
plot3d( x, y, z, alpha=0, theta=270);

e = gce();        // Get current entity handle.
e.color_flag = 1; // Color according to z

f = gcf();                        // Get current figure handle.
f.color_map = hotcolormap(512);     // Make it a heat color map
```

### Docs

According to the [plot3d docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/plot3d.html) and [surface_properties docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/surface_properties.html) the `color_flag` can be used to:

> **color_flag:** This field is used to specify the algorithm used to set facets' colors.
>
> Note that the rules on color_mode, foreground and hiddencolor are
>   still applied to this case.
>
> ...
>
> **color_flag == 1**
>
> All facets are painted using one color index per facet proportional to
>   z. The minimum z value is painted using the index 1 color while the
>   maximum z value is painted using highest color index. The edges of the
>   facets can be additionaly drawn depending on the value of color_mode
>   (see above).

### Resulting image

[image]